# Swapping Frame for ContentControl breaks relative bindings in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Just had a curious incident that illustrates I don't understand relative bindings in WPF as well as I thought I did.

The main application consists of a Window, underneath which is a ContentControl that holds the current ViewModel (we're using MVVM).

In many of the Views there's code a bit like this that binds back to functions on the main view, the one that binds to the window itself:

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
Path=DataContext.CommandOnMainViewModel}"
```

And this works fine and everything is right and good with the world.

However I recently changed the main window so that it loaded the ViewModels into a Frame rather than a ContentControl, in order to see if we could get any value out of the navigation controls included in the Frame.

The application appeared to work fine at first, but it soon became apparent that all the relative bindings like the one above had broken - the application simply wasn't finding those commands on the DataContext anymore.

I thought that RelativeSource FindAncestor just went back up the tree until it bumped into an object of the specified type and bound to that. In which case substituting a ContentControl for a Frame should have made no difference.

But it does. Why, and what can I do to fix it?

EDIT: Flipping through some reference books, I found this statement: "The Frame control holds arbitrary content, just like all the other content controls, but it isolates the content from the rest of the UI." So that explains why it doesn't work. If there's an easy workaround for this, it'd still be appreciated.